# (Basic) Errors with questionare

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and I'm trying to get this code to work. I can only make basic programs and I feel that I'm well out of my depth! If you think there is another way that I can do this I am open to any suggestions. Here is my code:

```
import time
right = 0
again = 0
name = 0
wrong = 0
questionNumber = 0
questions = [
    {'text': 'What is the population of New Zealand?',
     'choices': ('6.7m', '3.2m', '5.1m', '4.5m'),
     'answer': {'D', '4.5M'},
     },
    {'text': 'What year did the first european set foot on '
     'New Zealand? (Abel Tasman)',
     'choices': ('1830', '1543', '1642', '1765'),
     'answer': {'C', '1642'},
     },
    {'text': 'How High is Mt Cook New Zealand?',
     'choices': ('3,724m', '4,272m', '3,893m', '2,280m'),
     'answer': {'A', '3724'},
     },
    {'text': 'What is the biggest lake in New Zealand?',
     'choices': ('Taupo', 'Te Anau', 'Wanaka', 'Wakatipu'),
     'answer': {'A', 'Taupo'},
     },
    {'text': 'What Percentage of New Zealands population are Maori?',
     'choices': ('25%', '45%', '10%', '15%'),
     'answer': {'D', '15'},
     },

]

print("Please Enter Your Name")
name = input()

def questionAsk(question):
    global right, wrong, questions, questionNumber, name
    print(question['text'])
    for i in questions:
        print(chr(i+ord('A')) + ': ', choice)

    return input('> ').upper() in question['answer']

for question in questions:
        if questionAsk(question):
            print ("Right")
            right = right + 1
            questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
            print()
            print("So far",name,"You have got",right,"Answers right,",wrong,"Answers wrong and you have completed",questionNumber,"Questions")
            print()
        else:
            print ("Wrong")
            wrong = wrong + 1
            questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
            print()
            print("So far",name,"You have got",right,"Answers right,",wrong,"Answers wrong and you have completed",questionNumber,"Questions")
            print()
print("Well done",name,"! you have completed my Questionare! You have got",right,"Out of a possible 10 questions correct and",wrong,"You have completed",questionNumber,"Questions!")
print()
print()
print("Do you want to play again?")
print("Y: Yes")
print("N: No")
again = input()
```

And heres the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jason/Downloads/Python.py", line 44, in <module>
    if questionAsk(question):
  File "C:/Users/Jason/Downloads/Python.py", line 39, in questionAsk
    print(chr(i+ord('A')) + ': ', choice)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'int'
```

Thanks so much for your help! if you have a better way of creating this questionnaire I am open to any suggestions!

Kind Regards,
User

Answer (score 0):

Change for loop in function questionAsk this way:

```
for i,choice in enumerate(question['choices']):
    print(chr(i+ord('A')) + ': ', choice)
```

Comment: While I fully agree with the correctness of your answer, I would suggest that you explain it a little bit more in detail, to help the OP to gain some understanding of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

First about the errors you are having. It is caused by the `+` in the `print` function. The reason for that is the `+` operator doesn't know how to "add" an instance of `dict` and an instance of `str`.
I'm not quite sure what are you trying to do there so if you explain it I could be more helpful.

Second about your code. Since you are a beginner to Python here are some basics:

1. There is no need here for global variables. You can put everything here in one (or two) function(s) and get rid of them globals.
2. String formatting. It will be easier if you just follow [this](http://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting).
3. That goes for using `print()` just to print a newline as well.
4. The next step - Classes. What happens if you want to add questions? you would have to hard-code them. Try to make your code more versatile.

For a quick and simple example:

```
class Question(object):

    def __init__(self, text, options, ans):
        self.text = text
        self.options = options
        self.answer = ans

    def ask(self):
        print(self.text)
        for i, opt in enumerate(self.options):
            print('%d: %s' % (i, opt))

    def check_ans(self, ans):
        if answer not in (1, 2, 3, 4):
            print('invalid answer')
        else:
            if ans == self.answer:
                print('correct!')
            else:
                print('wrong answer')
```

There is a lot more to learn to make this better. Good luck!

Comment: I have to disagree with you to some degree. There is no apparent need for classes here. At least not for making the program handle more questions. That is just as easily done without classes. Adding classes increases the design complexity for little gain in small programs like this. In Python it is quite OK to _not_ use classes. Another, unrelated, note is that your answer check is not as intelligent as in the OP. There the correct answer can be either the letters `'A'` to `'D'` or the actual string that is the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for the review. You are right that the check answer is not as the OP intended but this is a simplified version so I didn't aim to be as accurate. And sure, you could create more questions using a function. but then printing (asking) the question would be a bit more complicated than `q.ask()`. Maybe for a beginner it would be better to use a function.